# Can I set Thunderbird to move all spam/junk mail to my inbox instead?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

My upstream e-mail provider (Tormail) has a horrendous false-positive rate. There is also no webmail address book thingy that can whitelist stuff. Almost all of my friends' mail goes into the junk folder - in fact, there might be a bug as I don't recall *anything* going into the regular inbox except e-mails to myself!

Thunderbird has its own spam filter. Can I tell it to automatically redirect mails going into the junk folder into the inbox, and then do it's own spam filtering?

Comment: If Thunderbird has the ability to filter email and Thunderbird pulls emails marked as spam by your email provider.  You can indeed setup a filter to move all mail to a specific folder.  You could also use say Google Mail, Outlook, Yahoo to POP3 which should place all recieved email together

Comment: How would one setup that filter?

Comment: Follow the guide here: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-up-message-filters-in-thunderbird/